# How to append wordpress editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wp-editor

I am trying to append WP_editor in javascript.

I can echo wp_editor which creates text area statically , but my requirement is that when the user clicks on a button then wp_edior should attach to div

```
    $("a").click(function(e){
    $(div).append("<?php echo wp_editor('',1,'');?>

    });
```

Comment: you will need to post to php to generate a **new** wp_editor on demand, since every wp_editor has associated ids and scripts and setup etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wp_editor in the normal PHP execution, and hide it using CSS (`display:none;`). Then, when the User clicks the button, use Javascript to change display to block.

```
document.getElementById('THE_ID_OF_EDITOR').style.display="block";
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not meet the requirements. wp_editor has uqinue id and on every single click i want to add a wp_editor ..Putting wp_Editor in html as hidden div and then showing div is not appropriate as if if want 30 wp_editors should i have 30 hidden divs ? but i dont know who much editors user want what should i do

Comment: Add a wp_editor in starting, and then create its copies with Javascript and use IDs as editor1, editor2, .....